# Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended

Tags: java, json, ssl

I tried to access my simple API call through POSTMAN. It didn't work whereas it is working in browser.

Tried after making changes in Database connection URL as below.

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BLOG_ERA?useSSL=false

Even it didn't work.

> WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity
>   verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+
>   and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default
>   if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing
>   applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set
>   to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting
>   useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server
>   certificate verification.

Comment: This is just a warning, not an error. You must be using http instead of https in postman.

Comment: I am using http no result. I want to test all my APIs through postman. So I want to fix this.

Comment: What URL are you calling in postman? Also, "didn't work" isn't enough, please show us the error, or is it timing out?

Comment: oops..!! It worked now with http://localhost:8080/. Seems the issue is with URL. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Well, you either want to put up  a self answer, or you delete your the whole question. If you want to keep things around, make sure they are of value for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning and not an error.

If it is working in the browser and not in Postman, the problem is most likely in the URL and not in the database connection. Make sure you are using the exact same URL in Postman. Most people make the mistake of using `http` in the URL in Postman instead of `https`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just because of an incorrect URL given in POSTMAN. I am able to get the response in POSTMAN. 
It is nowhere related to the SSL warning.